# Mount Outlook Shared Folders In Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, microsoft-outlook-2010, shared-folders, exchange-2010

My workplace uses Shared Folders in Outlook to share documents, and I would like to view or mount them in Windows Explorer instead of having to view them through Outlook 2010. They have an Exchange 2010 server. Is this possible? I will provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this in Exchange 2010, but [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397221%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx) suggests that it may work.

Add a "network place" for the /public path on your Exchange web server. In Win2000 and XP this is fairly straightforward from My Network Places > Add Network Place. In Vista and Windows 7 you have to call the wizard up with this unwieldy command from the run menu:

```
rundll32.exe shwebsvc.dll,AddNetPlaceRunDll
```

The URL you are adding will look something like:

```
https://outlook.huskehnsworkplace.com/public
```

You should be prompted for your username and password with an option to store them.

Follow the wizard through to completion (choosing a sensible name along the way) and the folder should then appear under My Computer/Computer in Explorer.

If you open it you should be able to browse through files as if it was a standard filestore.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I wonder if it has something to do with how the Exchange server is configured? It might not be possible.